# Is it always a good practice to using Scanner for scanning consol input and close it?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Below is the code i usually use to read objects from console:

```
try(Scanner n1 = new Scanner(System.in))
    {
        num = n1.nextInt();
    }
```

I don't get any memory leaks error so am I correct in thinking that this gets the work done. I wanna know how things works here. Please do not use "bufferedreader" topic or any other* as an alternative to read from console. I wanna how things with "Scanner" works.

Comment: @NeerajJain: As a matter of fact i don't get error. Till now i have practice more than 30 programs and every single one executes just fine.

Comment: @NeerajJain this is try with resource so OP wont get error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `try-with-resources` statement will close the `Scanner` after it is done. Since the `Scanner` is attached to the `System.in`, it will also close the standard input stream and you won't be able to read input after that. For example, the following code would cause a `java.util.NoSuchElementException`:

```
try(Scanner n1 = new Scanner(System.in))
{
    num = n1.nextInt();
}

try(Scanner n2 = new Scanner(System.in))
{
    num = n2.nextInt();  // will throw an exception
}
```

Comment: I get it now. So in case if i have to read from the consol what should i do?

Comment: You can simply avoid using the `try-with-resources` here. Create only one `Scanner` and close it when you no longer need to use it.

Comment: Got it, so i can put the entire thing if i want. Thanks